# Get keyword ideas by page URL in Google AdWords API

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get keyword ideas from AdWords API by page URL, but so far I'm only able to get keywords list by another keyword.

What I want to do is possible via web interface, but as for API, [docs say](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201509/TargetingIdeaService.IdeaType) that the only available value for `ideaType` property is `KEYWORD`.

Are there any alternatives for `ideaType`, maybe via creating a new campaign, or something else?

I'm using PHP.

I'm new to Google AdWords. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I misunderstood the goal of `ideaType` property. This property **is not** the input search parameters type.

For getting keyword ideas by URL you can use [`RelatedToUrlSearchParameter` class](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201509/TargetingIdeaService.RelatedToUrlSearchParameter).

In my case code looks like following (the most relevant part):

```
$selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector();
$selector->requestType = 'IDEAS';
$selector->ideaType = 'KEYWORD';
$selector->requestedAttributeTypes = array('KEYWORD_TEXT', 'SEARCH_VOLUME', 'CATEGORY_PRODUCTS_AND_SERVICES');

$relatedToUrlSearchParameter = new RelatedToUrlSearchParameter();
$url = $_GET['url'];
$relatedToUrlSearchParameter->urls = array($url);
$selector->searchParameters[] = $relatedToUrlSearchParameter;
```

Comment: I am doing the same steps while trying to get keyword ideas for a url. But, I am getting a keyword "red herring" in reply.

Comment: @TanmayVarun: I think it's because you use a test account to retrieve keywords